# Linear Smoothers and cross validation. That is easy, but is it?

Tags: cross-validation, smoothing, nonparametric-regression

Consider the nonparametric regression problem $Y_i=m(x_i)+\epsilon_i$. Let $m_h$ be the estimator based on smoothing parameter $h$
$$\widehat{\mbox{MSE}}(h) =  n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n \Big(  \frac{Y_i-\hat{m}_h(x_i)}{1-S_{ii}}    \Big)^2 .$$

That is based on the assumption that the estimator just reweighs the other observations. This is obviously true for Kernel smoothers, but not true for $k$-nearest neighbors.

What about Splines and local polynomial regression?